# Cell Gradient Fill Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have two functions here, each one displays the gradient slightly differently with up to 5 gradients.

Function 1:

```
Function addCellColor(ByVal c As Range, ByVal color As Long)
    Dim c1 As Long, c2 As Long, c3 As Long, c4 As Long

    'creates a gradient pattern if one doesn't already exist
    With c.Interior
        If .color = 16777215 Then
            .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
            .gradient.Degree = 0
            .gradient.ColorStops.Clear
        End If
    End With

    ' adds gradient color to cell up to 5 colors
    If Not c.Interior.gradient Is Nothing Then
        With c.Interior.gradient
            ' if the cell is already colored
            If .ColorStops.count <> 0 Then
                Select Case .ColorStops.count
                    Case 2
                        If .ColorStops(1).color = .ColorStops(2).color Then
                            c1 = .ColorStops(1).color
                            .ColorStops.Clear
                            .ColorStops.Add(0).color = c1
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.45).color = c1
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.55).color = color
                            .ColorStops.Add(1).color = color
                        End If
                    Case 4
                        If .ColorStops(1).color <> color And .ColorStops(2).color <> color And .ColorStops(3).color <> color And .ColorStops(4).color <> color Then
                            c1 = .ColorStops(1).color: c2 = .ColorStops(3).color
                            .ColorStops.Clear
                            .ColorStops.Add(0).color = c1
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.28).color = c1
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.38).color = c2
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.61).color = c2
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.71).color = color
                            .ColorStops.Add(1).color = color
                        End If
                    Case 6
                        If .ColorStops(1).color <> color And .ColorStops(2).color <> color And .ColorStops(3).color <> color _
                        And .ColorStops(4).color <> color And .ColorStops(5).color <> color And .ColorStops(6).color <> color Then
                            c1 = .ColorStops(1).color: c2 = .ColorStops(3).color: c3 = .ColorStops(5).color
                            .ColorStops.Clear
                            .ColorStops.Add(0).color = c1
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.2).color = c1
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.3).color = c2
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.45).color = c2
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.55).color = c3
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.7).color = c3
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.8).color = color
                            .ColorStops.Add(1).color = color
                        End If
                    Case 8
                        If .ColorStops(1).color <> color And .ColorStops(2).color <> color And .ColorStops(3).color <> color And .ColorStops(4).color <> color _
                        And .ColorStops(5).color <> color And .ColorStops(6).color <> color And .ColorStops(7).color <> color And .ColorStops(8).color <> color Then
                            c1 = .ColorStops(1).color: c2 = .ColorStops(3).color: c3 = .ColorStops(5).color: c4 = .ColorStops(7).color
                            .ColorStops.Clear
                            .ColorStops.Add(0).color = c1
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.15).color = c1
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.25).color = c2
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.35).color = c2
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.45).color = c3
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.55).color = c3
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.65).color = c4
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.75).color = c4
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.85).color = color
                            .ColorStops.Add(1).color = color
                        End If
                End Select
            ' if cell has no colors yet
            Else
                .ColorStops.Add(0).color = color
                .ColorStops.Add(1).color = color
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

Output (completes in 2 minutes and 10 seconds when ran on a collection of ~4500 items):

[image: Function 1 output]

Function 2:

```
Function addCellColor1(ByVal c As Range, ByVal color As Long)
    Dim c1 As Long, c2 As Long, c3 As Long, c4 As Long

    'creates a gradient pattern if one doesn't already exist
    With c.Interior
        If .color = 16777215 Then
            .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
            .gradient.Degree = 0
            .gradient.ColorStops.Clear
        End If
    End With

    ' adds gradient color to cell up to 5 colors
    If Not c.Interior.gradient Is Nothing Then
        With c.Interior.gradient
            ' if the cell is already colored
            If .ColorStops.count <> 0 Then
                Select Case .ColorStops.count
                    Case 2
                        If .ColorStops(1).color = .ColorStops(2).color Then
                            .ColorStops(2).color = color
                        ElseIf .ColorStops(1).color <> color And .ColorStops(2).color <> color Then
                            c1 = .ColorStops(1).color: c2 = .ColorStops(2).color
                            .ColorStops.Clear
                            .ColorStops.Add(0).color = c1
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.5).color = c2
                            .ColorStops.Add(1).color = color
                        End If
                    Case 3
                        If .ColorStops(1).color <> color And .ColorStops(2).color <> color And .ColorStops(3).color <> color Then
                            c1 = .ColorStops(1).color: c2 = .ColorStops(2).color: c3 = .ColorStops(3).color
                            .ColorStops.Clear
                            .ColorStops.Add(0).color = c1
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.33).color = c2
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.66).color = c3
                            .ColorStops.Add(1).color = color
                        End If
                    Case 4
                        If .ColorStops(1).color <> color And .ColorStops(2).color <> color And .ColorStops(3).color <> color And .ColorStops(4).color <> color Then
                            c1 = .ColorStops(1).color: c2 = .ColorStops(2).color: c3 = .ColorStops(3).color: c4 = .ColorStops(4).color
                            .ColorStops.Clear
                            .ColorStops.Add(0).color = c1
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.25).color = c2
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.5).color = c3
                            .ColorStops.Add(0.75).color = c4
                            .ColorStops.Add(1).color = color
                        End If
                End Select
            ' if cell has no colors yet
            Else
                .ColorStops.Add(0).color = color
                .ColorStops.Add(1).color = color
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

Output (completes in 1 minute and 12 seconds when ran on a collection of ~4500 items):

[image: Function 2 output]

It is recommended to have the below function run before this one

```
Function Opt_Start()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End function
```

Particularly looking for an optimization review since the functions take a long time to run when it is ran in a loop.

Additional info:

I have collected a large amount of data in a VBA Collection that looks like this:

[image: Collection]

The data collection for this (approx 4500 items) takes about 5 seconds, the gradient fill takes minutes.

This is all I am permitted to share: This is how the cell colors are determined.

```
Private Function FormatDocument()
    Dim p As FormulaParameter
    Dim green As Long, orange As Long, lRed As Long, dRed As Long, magenta As Long, dGrey As Long
    Debug.Print ("Formatting Cells")
    green = RGB(146, 208, 80)
    orange = RGB(255, 192, 0)
    lRed = RGB(255, 80, 80)
    dRed = RGB(192, 0, 0)
    magenta = RGB(252, 117, 255)
    dGrey = RGB(120, 120, 120)

    For Each p In coll
        If Not p Is Nothing Then
            With p
                ' Error 2: Step name not found for the operation parameter
                    ' this error will just be logged no format changes

                'Cell is orange if the value in that cell has been modified at all. Overrides others.
                    ' if error says "Parameter was tracked successfully." change the formula and unit level defenition if not = "Operation default"
                    ' if it is an operation default value, change the unit parameter to its default value
                    If .newValue = "Operation Default" Then
                        '********************** This block will change UP level parameter ***************************************
                        'If Not .uParam Is Nothing Then
                        '    .uParam.Offset(0, 1).value = .defValue
                        '    Call addCellColor(.uParam.Offset(0, 1), orange)
                        '    Call ReplaceUnits(.uParam.Offset(0, 2))
                        'End If
                        '********************** This block will change UP level parameter ***************************************

                        '************ This line will change OP level parameter and delete UP parameter **************************
                        If Not .oParam2 Is Nothing Then
                            .oParam2.Offset(0, 1).value = .defValue
                            Call addCellColor(.oParam2.Offset(0, 1), orange)
                            Call ReplaceUnits(.oParam2.Offset(0, 2))
                            If Not .uParam Is Nothing Then
                                .uParam.Offset(0, 1).value = ""
                                .uParam.value = ""
                                .uParam.Offset(0, -1).value = "VALUE"
                                .uParam.Offset(0, -1).Font.color = vbRed
                            End If
                        End If
                        '************ This line will change OP level parameter and delete UP parameter **************************

                    Else
                        If Not .fParam Is Nothing And .newValue <> "" Then .fParam.Offset(0, .fOffset).value = .newValue
                        If Not .fParam Is Nothing And .newValue <> "" Then Call addCellColor(.fParam.Offset(0, .fOffset), orange)
                    End If
                ' Error 10: there was not a unit parameter for the corresponding operation parameter on uTab
                    ' This will also have a default value put into the value in UP
                    If InStr(1, .error, "Error 10:") > 0 And .newValue = "Operation Default" Then
                    '    .uParam.Offset(0, 1).value = .defValue                                            ' this will change if changing at operation level
                    '    If Not .uParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.uParam.Offset(0, 1), orange)
                    '************************************************ added for op level change
                        If Not .oParam2 Is Nothing Then
                            .oParam2.Offset(0, 1).value = .defValue
                            Call addCellColor(.oParam2.Offset(0, 1), orange)
                            Call ReplaceUnits(.oParam2.Offset(0, 2))
                            If Not .oParam1 Is Nothing Then
                                .oParam1.Offset(0, 4).value = ""
                                .oParam1.Offset(0, 2).value = "VALUE"
                                .oParam1.Offset(0, 2).Font.color = vbRed
                            End If
                        End If
                    '************************************************ added for op level change
                    End If



                'Cell is green if the value, or parameter in that cell was able to be tracked successfully throughout the two documents.
                    ' catches unit level parameters
                    ' if error says "Parameter was tracked successfully."
                    If .error = "Parameter was tracked successfully." Or .error = "Parameter is a Unit Procedure level defenition" Then
                        If Not .uParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.uParam, green)
                        If Not .oParam1 Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.oParam1, green)
                        If Not .oParam2 Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.oParam2, green)
                        If Not .rParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.rParam, green)
                        If Not .pParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.pParam, green)
                        If Not .pParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.pParam.Offset(0, .pOffset), green)
                        If Not .pParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.pParam.Offset(0, .dOffset), green)
                        If .error = "Parameter is a Unit Procedure level defenition" And Not .fParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.fParam.Offset(0, .fOffset), green)

                    End If

                'Cell is light red due to a possible mismatch in the R_ parameter from the OP tabs to the PH tabs or vice versa.

                    ' Error 1: Parameter in formula was not found in an operation OR
                    ' Error 2: Step name not found for the operation parameter OR
                    ' Error 3: Operation tab was not found
                    ' Error 4: Operation parameter not found in operation tab
                    ' Error 6: Recipe parameter not found in phase tab
                    ' Error 8: Recipe parameter in the phase was not found in the operation
                    ' Error 9: operation parameter from the operation was not found in the Unit procedure
                    If InStr(1, .error, "Error 1:") > 0 Or InStr(1, .error, "Error 2:") > 0 Or InStr(1, .error, "Error 4:") > 0 _
                    Or InStr(1, .error, "Error 6:") > 0 Or InStr(1, .error, "Error 8:") > 0 Or InStr(1, .error, "Error 9:") > 0 _
                    Or InStr(1, .error, "Error 3:") > 0 Then
                        If Not .pParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.pParam, lRed)
                        If Not .pParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.pParam.Offset(0, .dOffset), lRed)
                        If Not .pParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.pParam.Offset(0, .pOffset), lRed)
                        If Not .rParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.rParam, lRed)
                        If Not .oParam1 Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.oParam1, lRed)
                        If Not .oParam2 Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.oParam2, lRed)
                        If Not .uParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.uParam, lRed)
                        If Not .fParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.fParam.Offset(0, .fOffset), lRed)
                    End If

                'Cell is dark red if the parameter is blank in the parameter value document.
                    ' Error 10: there was not a unit parameter for the corresponding operation parameter on uTab
                    ' or the parameter is empty in phase tab
                    If InStr(1, .error, "Error 10:") > 0 Or (Not .pParam Is Nothing And .newValue = "" And .pOffset <> 0) Then
                        If Not .pParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.pParam, dRed)
                        If Not .pParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.pParam.Offset(0, .dOffset), dRed)
                        If Not .pParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.pParam.Offset(0, .pOffset), dRed)
                        If Not .rParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.rParam, dRed)
                        If Not .uParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.uParam, dRed)
                        If Not .oParam1 Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.oParam1, dRed)
                        If Not .oParam2 Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.oParam2, dRed)
                        If Not .fParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.fParam.Offset(0, .fOffset), dRed)
                    End If

                'Cell is magenta if there were no parameter values found for this phase on this column/formula.
                    ' Error 7: There does not exist parameter value for this phase on this formula
                    ' Error 5: Phase tab was not found
                If InStr(1, .error, "Error 5:") > 0 Or InStr(1, .error, "Error 7:") > 0 Then
                        If Not .fParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.fParam.Offset(0, .fOffset), magenta)
                        If Not .uParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.uParam, magenta)
                        If Not .oParam1 Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.oParam1, magenta)
                        If Not .oParam2 Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.oParam2, magenta)
                        If Not .rParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.rParam, magenta)
                    End If

                'Cell is dark grey if the value, or parameter in that cell is operation default. (Some may be light grey)
                    ' para.newValue = operation default
                    If .newValue = "Operation Default" Then
                        If Not .rParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.rParam, dGrey)
                        If Not .oParam1 Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.oParam1, dGrey)
                    If Not .oParam2 Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.oParam2, dGrey)
                        If Not .uParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.uParam, dGrey)
                        If Not .fParam Is Nothing Then Call addCellColor(.fParam.Offset(0, .fOffset), dGrey)
                    End If
                'Cell is white if that cell was not able to be checked across documents, or invalid entries exist. Most commonly the cells are white because
                    'they did not exist in the formula but they did in the operation, or they did not exist in the parameter document. Cells white in parameter
                    'document because they were never looked at due to mismatched names.
            End With
        End If
    Next p
End Function
```

[Linked question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54831083/optimize-my-gradient-fill-function-and-determine-why-is-takes-so-long-to-run?noredirect=1#comment96438436_54831083)

Comment: Welcome to CR! I've added the runtimes from the linked SO post (I'd recommend removing the SO question) - curious what the inputs are for such times, surely it doesn't take 1-2 minutes to fill up *just one cell*? Feel free to [edit] your post to include the code that uses these functions, too!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - Thanks for the help you are giving me, much appreciated! I've edited the post with some more info but it is all I am allowed to share. There are MANY cells being filled. My main issue is one function takes longer than the other, but do the same thing really.

Comment: That's perfect! I don't think having the two functions is necessary though - just including the one that's actually being used should be good enough. Side note, you might want to look into what low-hanging fruit [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck)'s *code inspections* can find & fix. (note: I and a bunch of reviewers monitoring the VBA tag, contribute to this free/open-source project; star us on GitHub if you like! see the [tag:rubberduck] tag for more details)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon -  I know about Rubberduck, but I am not able to run it on this work computer, it unfortunately gets blocked. It would be very useful.

Comment: Instead of clearing all of the colorstops and re-adding them, you could adjust the position of the existing stops and just add the one new one.  That might be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following my suggestion in the comments, turns out this is only slightly faster: for 5 colors over 5000 cells it's ~6.1 sec vs. ~8.5 sec for your Function 2...

```
Sub addCellColor2(ByVal c As Range, ByVal color As Long)

    Dim step, pos, i As Long, n As Long, cStop As ColorStop

    With c.Interior
    If .color = 16777215 Then
        .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
        .Gradient.Degree = 0
        With .Gradient.ColorStops
            .Item(1).color = color
            .Item(2).color = color
        End With
        Exit Sub
    End If
    End With

    With c.Interior.Gradient

            'see if this color already exists
            For Each cStop In .ColorStops
                If cStop.color = color Then Exit Sub
            Next cStop

            n = .ColorStops.Count
            If n = 2 And .ColorStops(1).color = .ColorStops(2).color Then
                .ColorStops(2).color = color
                Exit Sub
            End If

            step = Round(1 / (n), 3)
            pos = step
            For i = 2 To n
                .ColorStops(i).Position = pos
                pos = pos + step
            Next i
            .ColorStops.Add(1).color = color

     End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Sped it up a little bit yeah. My boss really wants Function 1 unfortunately and I have not been able to work out the math for just adding these stops easily. I think it will just have to stick to being a time consuming macro. We will only be running it for a few weeks anyways a few times a day, so not too much time is lost.